# New Laptop Screen, Low Resolution

Tags: laptop, display, resolution

I have a Sager NP9130 laptop. I had a 1920x1080 resolution.

Recently my screen was cracked, and I grabbed a screen from a local PC repair shop to replace it. I'm currently using it, and it works great, but I can't seem to get the resolution past 1366x768. I've tried everything that Google and I can think of (update drivers) to no avail. And sadly, I didn't write down the model of the screen I purchased before I installed it.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible that this 15.6" LED screen has a max resolution of 1366x768, or if there's any hope. If it's worth me taking the laptop apart again to get the model number, let me know.

Thank you so much in advance, if you need any more information I'm ready to assist

Comment: Yes, it is possible for a 15.6" to have that poor of a resolution.  Take a look at how many laptops in that size have it, it's sad.  Sounds like yours must be one of them.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the screen can't handle a larger resolution. Have you checked to make sure the graphics card wasn't damaged in the process?

Comment: I can't imagine the graphics card is damaged, my wife simply pinched the screen too hard, cracking it.  It wasn't dropped or anything

Comment: It's hard to know without more info on the replacement screen itself, but the way you've described it makes it sound like it just has a lower PPI than your old display. 1366x768 is pretty common resolution for 15.6" displays. From 1080 to 768, you've gone from 141.21 PPI to 100.45 PPI.

Comment: I started writing answer to say that "Yes, a lower res. display can be used on many laptops. If you are unlucky you picked the wrong replacement part. Can you look which part you had (e.g. `SKU - S1R324`)"?

However the more I look the more I am convinced I am wrong. 
All site I find seem to list 1920x1080 screens. At least 3 different versions of them, but all 1920x1080.

Comment: try opening a test image like this: http://sunmaiblog.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/section-b-mp4-media-player-classic-home-cinema-v1-4-b3.png if the pixels in the image are completely sharp and don't slightly blur over to the other pixels of the LCD, it'll be running at native resolution.